# What is minimum and maximum probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

What is meant by minimum and maximum probability of an event. I came across a questions that asks minimum and maximum probability of three heads in three coins are flipped. We need to find minimum and maximum probability in two cases

1. When all three coins are not independent
2. All pairs of coins are mutually independent

The probability of head and tail on each individual coin is 0.5. I am more concerned on how to approach this problem rather than its solution. So far, I am unable to find any material on minimum and maximum probability.

Comment: For the first one, you can alter the probability by altering the dependence.  For example, suppose the second toss can't be the same as the first.  Then the probability of getting three $H's$ in a row is $0$.  Can't get lower than that, but you still have to find the max.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on this please?

Comment: Sure.  If the tosses are independent, the answer is $\frac 18$.  However, if they are dependent the answer will depend on the dependence.  I gave one form of the dependence which made the answer $0$.  On the other side, if we assume that all tosses are the same then the answer is $\frac 12$. That's the maximum.

Answer (score 1):

Assign probability $1/4$ to each of the  outcomes TTT, HHT, THH, THH. (That is, spread the mass uniformly on the subset where there is an even number of heads.  One can do this by flipping the first two coins independently, and then using the parity of the first two to determine the output of the 3d flip.  At any rate, in this case, $P(HHH)=0$.  This strange probability law evidently minimizes $P(HHH)$.

Now assign probability $1/2$ to the outcomes HHH and TTT.  Now $P(HHH)=1/2$, which is maximal.  (If $P(HHH)>1/2$ we'd make the first coin unfair, giving it probability $>1/2$.)

That's the answer.  A general principle here is that the joint probability law is constrained by having certain marginals.  The constraints are linear (*these* probabilities must add up to *that*) and so the OP's problem boils down to a linear programming problem.

Answer (score -1):

The probability of three heads with three FAIR coins is $({1\over 2})^3$. The min/max may relate to conditional probabilities where the chance of getting heads on the seconds coin depends on what happened with the first coin etc. I'm only guessing that it may mean this as I have never encountered min/max in probability questions such as this.

Comment: "The probability of three heads with three FAIR coins is $({1\over 2})^3$" If they are independent, yes. Otherwise, not always.